# Node, BodyParser bad json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, body-parser

I have this code in javascript:

```
var express = require('express');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
})

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
})
```

From a rails app I am suppose to receive this json in the body:

```
 {"content": "some content", "test":"some tests"}
```

but instead I receive this one:

```
{ '{"content":"some content","test":"some test"}' : ''}
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong??

This is the way the JSON is sent:

```
response = JSON.parse RestClient.post("#{test_runner_url}/test", {content: content, test: test}.to_json)
```

Comment: Are you sending your JSON with the correct headers? Better yet, how are you sending it?

Comment: Hi, this is the way the JSON is sent: 

**response = JSON.parse RestClient.post("#{test_runner_url}/test", {content: content, test: test}.to_json)**

Comment: This is not Ruby on Rails related question. Please remove this tag.

Comment: I don't think the node app code is helping in the question. We need the code where you are sending the Json request to node app.

Comment: Try checking the value of `{content: content, test: test}.to_json` before sending to node app.

Comment: What language is that code in?

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin I think it is, since the node part of code seems to be ok. But we do not know what's happening at the rails part of the app, how the sending is done and what data is being sent.

Comment: @KevinB it is ruby code

Comment: Based on the response in node, i would assume ruby is sending the data as form params rather than json.

Comment: Yup... that's true... the signature of `ResClient.post` method is `.post(url, payload, headers = {}, &block) ⇒ Object` where payload is supposed to be `string-encoded-post-body`.

Comment: You need to supply correct Mime-type by adding a `content-type` header  `RestClient.post("#{test_runner_url}/test", {content: content, test: test}.to_json, :content_type => 'application/json')`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Thanks for your answer, but if I add the content_type, the req.body is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was:

```
RestClient.post("#{test_runner_url}/test", {content: content, test: test}, :content_type => 'application/json')
```